# How to release a music collection from SonicStage

Tags: mp3

I have a friend who used SonicStage to digitize his music collection. Now he wants to be export the music to a more accessible format (for example mp3). The program is a few years old, and the only viable option seems to be to create mp3 CDs, which is an option in the program.

It would be easier to transfer directly to  a hard drive. But where are the actual music files stored, and how can they be converted?